# in new nav, clicking bounties button does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Starting from the home page, and clicking my saved tab for

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

I see that there are 7 bounties. However, if I click the blue button, nothing happens.

It works fine if I navigate directly to the page above, for example by clicking [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) under "Favorite Tags."

Comment: Not sure if it merits a separate report (or even qualifies as a bug), but: another difference is that if I navigate directly to that page, I get the [tag:r] wiki excerpt and corresponding links in a banner at the top (as before, in the old new nav), while this is missing if I navigate to my tab almost any other way.

Comment: It works if you refresh the page then immediately click the bounty button, but if you switch tabs before clicking the button it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.10.27.3789` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.27.2908` on sites).

Comment: I'm still seeing it if I follow the steps this OP takes to repro: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309295/1191259