# "Bounties" button is unresponsive

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, new-nav, user-interface

For custom tabs, the "bounties" button behaves unresponsive at times:

[image]

Specifically, this occurs if and only if I **switch from a tab with no active bounties to one with active bounties**. The button works perfectly fine after refreshing. It also works perfectly fine if I subsequently switch to another tab with active bounties.

Comment: It works that many times "after"...so when precisely does it NOT work??!?!?

Comment: @JonH Clarified it. I think I've grasped the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).